# save pre_save post_save предыдущее и новое значение поля

Tags: django, django-orm

Как можно в методе save() или обработчиках сигналов pre_save() / post_save() сравнить предыдущее и новое значения атрибута модели?

Answer (score 0):

Извините, а в чем проблема сравнивать атрибуты до save()? Перед тем как на место старого атрибута записать значение нового, посчитать разницу между ними или еще что-угодно. 
 Либо можно внутри вашей модели, помимо поля для текущего значения атрибута, создать еще одну модель, в которой будут хранится последовательности атрибутов, которые были раньше, тогда уж точно никаких проблем с сравнением предыдущих значений не будет. Могу привести пример.

```
class Potato(models.Model):
current_price = models.FloatField()

class PriceList(models.Model):
    price = models.FloatField()
```

Comment: Как-то привычнее работать в стиле триггеров БД, когда для каждого поля БД можно одновременно получить значение до правки и после правки и отреагировать на это проверкой валидности или выполнить какие-то манипуляции с данными.

Answer (score 0):

Сравнивать значения можно через `post_init`/`post_save`. Например так:

```
# receivers.py

@receiver(signal=models.signals.post_init, sender=YourModel)
def post_init_handler(instance, **kwargs):
    instance.original_name = instance.name

@receiver(signal=models.signals.post_save, sender=YourModel)
def post_save_handler(instance, **kwargs):
    if not instance.name == instance.original_name:
        # свойство name было изменено!
```